# While loop generating printf twice before asking for input?

Tags: c, while-loop, execution

For some reason this while loop executes twice and the strings are printed twice before it prompts for input. I had assumed it was that the input buffer had a character in it, but it does not to my knowledge. Any advice?

```
while (count >= 0 && stop != 83 && isClosed == 0) {
     printf("Percentage of Door Closed: %d\n",count);
     count -= 10;
     printf("If sensor detects object press 'S'\n");
     printf("Press any button to continue closing door\n");
     stop = getchar();
     if (count == 0) {
        isClosed=1;
     }
}
```

Output:

```
Percentage of Door Closed: 100
If sensor detects object press 'S'
Press any button to continue closing door
Percentage of Door Closed: 90
If sensor detects object press 'S'
Press any button to continue closing door
a
Percentage of Door Closed: 80
If sensor detects object press 'S'
Press any button to continue closing door
Percentage of Door Closed: 70
If sensor detects object press 'S'
Press any button to continue closing door
S
```

Comment: Make sure to realise that when you enter a single character and press enter, two characters are put into `stdin`: the character you entered, and the `\n` character from hitting enter.

Comment: Would doing a stop = null; before the while loop prevent this from occuring? I attempted it, however it still executes twice.

Comment: No, you have to consume and ignore the `\n`. You can do `while ((stop = getchar()) == '\n');` to skip all newline characters (the loop will loop and set `stop` to the next character until it's not a `\n`), or you can do what perreal or john bode said below.

Comment: if scanf("%c\n", characterVar) is used for two different character variables, the input is still stuck in the buffer..how do you flush it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're picking up the newline character that gets sent to the input stream when you type `S <Enter>`.  You can deal with this a couple of ways:

```
while ((stop = getchar()) == '\n'); // loops until it reads a non-newline
                                    // character
```

or

```
scanf(" %c", &stop); // note leading blank in format string; this tells scanf
                     // to skip any leading whitespace characters.
```

Comment: it seems that for the scanf("%c\n", &stop), when I press 'S' which is 83 in ASCII, the program does not exit. Any idea why? It seems stop is set to 1 after anything is entered the first go round.

Comment: @Muller Make sure that `stop` is of type `char` in this case. Furthermore, the character literal `'S'` has the value 83 on a system that uses ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you're starting the program with a key that also fills the buffer as some keys might generate several characters. Put a breakpoint at stop = getchar() and watch the value of stop when you step over it in the first iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today, since I didn't use `getchar` to get my character and instead used `scanf("%c", &stop)`. Once I changed the `%c` to `%s` for string retrieval it fixed the problem.

I'm not certain but `getString` might fix your issue as I think it would do the same thing.